# Cypress CY7C68013 in EPP mode code example

Tags: .net, cypress, parallel-port, epp

If read datasheet for Cypress Semiconductor IC CY7C68013(14, 15, 16)A, it's known that ICs can act as extended parallel port (EPP). Cypress Semiconductor provides a managed library CyUSB.dll for control this chips. I've searched many sources, including official forum, but did not found examples of code with EPP mode, that I need. Can anyone give some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a generic development board or custom hardware you have built. Likely, library CyUSB.dll won't be enough, you need to have correct firmware developed/uploaded to CY7C68013.

If you are purchased a CY7C68013 based usb to parallel converter, you should anyway see it as parallel port in Windows.

For a parallel interface app. note and general guidance, following may help:
https://community.cypress.com/thread/10786?start=0&tstart=0

http://www.cypress.com/documentation/code-examples/usb-hi-speed-code-examples

And following is an example for building USB to parallel port device using CY7C68013:
https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/basteln/PC/USB2LPT/ul-17.en.htm

Finally you may ask your question to Cypress forums, providing your application/hardware details.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thanks a lot!